# Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment'

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-intent

Google's documentation highlighting how to build an android app in java (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app#8) returns an error when using intents. On step 7, it says:

```
FirstFragmentDirections.ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(currentCount);
```

but my IDE consistently returns an error saying: Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment'. Ive tried resyncing the gradle files but im continuing to get this error. I've followed the steps to a T from my understanding but still unable to find the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It turns out in the nav_graph.xml file, I added the argument to the wrong fragment. I added the argument to fragment 1 because I assumed we should add it to the sending fragment. However, it needs to be added to the receiving fragment (fragment 2). In order to fix this:

1. Navigate to your nav_graph.xml file
2. Delete Current attributes
3. Add attributes to the receiving fragment.
   eg: if you are sending a value from fragment 1 to fragment 2, fragment 2 should have the argument added.

For understanding: When adding an attribute, classes are generated to allow communicating between fragments.

If I add an argument to fragment 2, the following classes will be generated:

- FirstFragmentDirections
- SecondFragmentArgs
- SecondFragmentDirections

If I add an argument to fragment 1, the following classes will be generated:

- SecondFragmentDirections
- FirstFragmentArgs
- FirstFragmentDirections

With each class containing the necessary methods to navigate to other classes. This is the reason I got the error previously: "Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment"
I was trying to navigate from the first fragment to the second fragment, but with the classes that had been generated, the method that I attempted to use was not available.