# Why can't my Android Studio resolve symbol 'ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment?'

Tags: java, android-fragments, referenceerror, android-studio-flamingo

Note: I am using Android Studio Flamingo with JDK20 and am a beginner.

I recently enabled safeargs in the build.gradle project ad module files, synced Gradle, and created an argument in my SecondFragment. However, when I type in `FirstFragmentDirections.ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(currentCount);`, Android studio says that it cannot resolve symbol `ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment`
Here is the site of the error:

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.random_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int currentCount = Integer.parseInt(showCountTextView.getText().toString());
                FirstFragmentDirections.ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment action =                            FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(currentCount);
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(action);
            }
        });
```

The button is supposed to send information about the situation another button by sending information from a textview.

Here is my build.gradle project file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.6.0-rc02"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
}
}
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}
```

Here is my build.gradle module file:

```
        plugins {
            id 'com.android.application'
        }
    
        apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
namespace 'com.example.myproject'
compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myproject"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {
constraints{
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
}

        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
    
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}
```

I tried changing the Gradle version, changing the android target SDK version, moving the `apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'` line outside of the plugins scope(it was originally `id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'`), changing the beginning part of the line to apply plugin and rebuilding Gradle. Other than that, I tried to view another question post([Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69546786/cannot-resolve-symbol-actionfirstfragmenttosecondfragment)) but, in response to the answer, I did put the argument in the right fragment. I thought that because android SDK 34 has not tested on Gradle 8.0.2 yet the problem might be related to the target SDK, but it was not.